# Sorting a Map of Structs - GOLANG

Tags: sorting, dictionary, struct, go

I have a map of structs that I am populating by streaming data to a Go program.  The way the map is updated is similar to the example below.

Once I have this map of structs populated, what is the best (or good) way to sort this map by the values of the `count` field in the struct?

```
package main

type data struct {
    count int64
}

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]data)
    m["x"] = data{0, 0}
    if xx, ok := m["x"]; ok {
        xx.count = 2
        m["x"] = xx
    } else {
        panic("X isn't in the map")
    }
}
```

This example can be run here: http://play.golang.org/p/OawL6QIXuO

Comment: You might want to consider using a B-Tree or a red-black tree for your purpose. As far as I recall there are no reference implementations in the Go library, but these data structures are not difficult to implement anyway.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As siritinga already pointed out, the elements of a `map` isn't ordered, so you cannot sort it.

What you can do is to create a `slice` and sort the elements using the `sort` package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type dataSlice []*data

type data struct {
    count int64
    size  int64
}

// Len is part of sort.Interface.
func (d dataSlice) Len() int {
    return len(d)
}

// Swap is part of sort.Interface.
func (d dataSlice) Swap(i, j int) {
    d[i], d[j] = d[j], d[i]
}

// Less is part of sort.Interface. We use count as the value to sort by
func (d dataSlice) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return d[i].count < d[j].count
}

func main() {
    m := map[string]*data {
        "x": {0, 0},
        "y": {2, 9},
        "z": {1, 7},
    }

    s := make(dataSlice, 0, len(m))

    for _, d := range m {
        s = append(s, d)
    }       

    // We just add 3 to one of our structs
    d := m["x"]
    d.count += 3

    sort.Sort(s)

    for _, d := range s {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", *d)
    }
}
```

Output:

> {count:1 size:7}
>   {count:2 size:9}
>   {count:3 size:0}

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Y0G4TupjnC)

**Edit**

Updated the example to use pointers and to include a map so that you can both do lookups and have a slice to sort over.

Comment: The reason I want to use a map is that I will be streaming millions of records through the program, and updating the counts of each key as the data is processed.  Does it make sense to populate the map, and convert it to a slice of structs?  The fields in the struct would just be the key and the count from the map.

Comment: @DJElbow It would make sense to have a map with pointers to your structs for doing lookups to add count, and at the same time maintain a slice with the pointers to the same structs. So, the slice and the map work on the same instances of the structs.

Comment: @siritinga Yepp, I saw :)  But I had some spare time, so I thought I could turn your comment to a practical example.

Comment: @DJElbow I updated the example to use a map as well so reflect the reply I gave you in previous comment.

Comment: Do you really need to sort it? You can send every element in the map and update the count with the `for range` construction, but every `for range` will get the elements map randomly. Keeping a million-length list sorted will take a lot of time. Maybe you can use a heap instead?

Comment: @siritinga I am not sure DJElbow means 'Unique records', only that the sum of count will be millions. But I agree, if there will be millions of unique records, your suggested solution (heap) or FUZxxl's suggestions (B-tree or red-black tree) might be a better choice.

Comment: Yes, I will be streaming millions of records, but the number of unique records will be in the 50k range.  But thanks for the heap suggestion.  For now I will try to implement the solution above.

Comment: @DJElbow Often good to start with a simple solution and optimize if needed. Remember to mark as Accepted if the answered solved your problem.

Comment: Works Great.  I also tried defining my slice as `type dataSlice []data`, and adjusted the relevant code. This worked as well.